# How to upload many text files from local computer to ftp using c# .net?

Tags: c#, ftp

I need to upload text file from local machine to ftp server using c#. 
I've tried folowing code but it did't work.

```
private bool UploadFile(FileInfo fileInfo) 
{
    FtpWebRequest request = null;
    try
    {
        string ftpPath = "ftp://www.tt.com/" + fileInfo.Name
        request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpPath);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftptest", "ftptest"); 
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Timeout = 60000; // 1 minute time out
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 15;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            int dataLength = (int)fs.Length;
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int bytesDownloaded = 0;
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                while (bytesRead < dataLength)
                {
                    bytesDownloaded = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    bytesRead = bytesRead + bytesDownloaded;
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesDownloaded);
                }
                requestStream.Close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;                
    }
    finally
    {
        request = null;
    }
    return false;
}// UploadFile
```

any suggestions ???

Comment: **How** didn't it work? Did it explode?

Comment: Your `try` block is completely useless, and destroys exception stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually send the request by calling `GetResponse()`.

You can also make your code much simpler by calling `fs.CopyTo(requestStream)`.

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered around with a bit ftp code and got the following, which seems to work pretty well for me.

**ftpUploadloc** is a ftp://ftp.yourftpsite.com/uploaddir/yourfilename.txt

**ftpUsername** and **ftpPassword** should be self explanatory.

Finally **currentLog** is the location of the file you're uploading.

Let me know how this worked out for you, if anyone else has any other suggestions I welcome those.

```
    private void ftplogdump()
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUploadloc);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(currentLog);
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


        // Remove before publishing
        Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        response.Close();
    }
```